# First iteration failing

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm fairly new to C++ but logically I thought this should have worked.

I have a function that takes an input from the user to set the memory allocation for an array:

```
void setarraynum(){
  string mystr;
  cout<<"Please enter the size of your array: ";
  getline(cin, mystr);
  stringstream(mystr)>>arraynum;
  array = new int [arraynum];
  cout<<"\n";
}
```

arraynum and array are globals set as:

```
int arraynum;
int * array;
```

I then have a function that takes the array inputs:

```
void setarray(){
  string mystr;
  cout<<"Please enter "<<arraynum<<" numbers:\n";
  for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
    getline(cin, mystr);
    stringstream(mystr)>>array[n];
  };
cout<<"\n";
}
```

The problem occurs when it comes to entering the array numbers, the first instance of the array (array[0]) gets automatically set to 0. As if the loop iterates the first iteration without asking the user for input. It then proceeds to ask the user as normal.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

*Edit (As requested, the entirety of the code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int arraynum;
int * array;
bool isin = false;
int input;
char order;

void insertionsortdesc(int a[]);
void insertionsortasc(int a[]);
void getarray(int a[]);
void isinarray(int a[], int b);

void setsearch();
void setarray();
void setarraynum();
void setorder();

int main(){

 cout<<"\n//// INPUT ////\n\n";

 setarraynum();
 setorder();
 setarray();
 setsearch();

 if(order=='a'){insertionsortasc(array);
 }else if(order=='d'){insertionsortdesc(array);};

 cout<<"//// OUTPUT ////\n\n";
 getarray(array);
 isinarray(array, input);

 return 0;
}

void setorder(){
 bool isvalid = false;

 while(!isvalid){
  cout<<"Ascending or Descending [a/d]: ";
  cin>>order;
  if(order=='a'||order=='d'){isvalid = true;
  }else{cout<<"Please enter a valid option!\n";};
 };

cout<<"\n";
}

void setarraynum(){
 string mystr;
 cout<<"Please enter the size of your array: ";
 getline(cin, mystr);
 stringstream(mystr)>>arraynum;
 array = new int [arraynum];
 cout<<"\n";
}

void setsearch(){
 string mystr;
 cout<<"Search for (int): ";
 getline(cin, mystr);
 stringstream(mystr)>>input;
 cout<<"\n";
}

void setarray(){
 string mystr;
 cout<<"Please enter "<<arraynum<<" numbers:\n";
 for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
  getline(cin, mystr);
  stringstream(mystr)>>array[n];
 };
cout<<"\n";
}

void insertionsortdesc(int a[]){
 for(int n=1; n<arraynum; n++){
  int key = a[n];
  int j = n-1;
  while((j>=0)&&(a[j]<key)){
   a[j+1] = a[j];
   j -= 1;
  };
  a[j+1]=key;
 }
}

void insertionsortasc(int a[]){
 for(int n=1; n<arraynum; n++){
  int key = a[n];
  int j = n-1;
  while((j>=0)&&(a[j]>key)){
   a[j+1] = a[j];
   j -= 1;
  };
  a[j+1]=key;
 }
}

void isinarray(int a[], int b){
 for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
  if(a[n] == b){
   isin = true;
   break;
  };
 };

 if(isin){
  cout<<b<<" is present in the given array.";
 }else{
  cout<<b<<" is not present in the given array.";
 };

 cout<<"\n\n";
}

void getarray(int a[]){
 cout<<"Sorted array sequence: ";
 for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
  cout<<a[n]<<", ";
 };
 cout<<"\n\n";
}
```

Comment: In `setarray`, print out each line you read by `getline`, to verify that the input is correct. Also, what's wrong with `std::vector`?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of `new[]` and make use of parameters and return values instead of using globals.

Comment: The first iteration doesn't print when I do this. Say I say the array memory allocation to 5, the setarray loop only asks for 4 inputs. I have no idea what std::vector is yet. I'm currently learning and using what I have learnt to make a simple sorting program.

Comment: You can `cin >> arraynum;` directly instead of `stringstream(mystr) >> arraynum;`. Unless you just want to learn how to use `stringstream`, there is no reason to use this indirection per my knowledge. :)

Comment: You might also want to step through the code line by line in a debugger, to see what really happens.

Comment: @chris so pass a parameter to setarraynum instead of asking for it in the function?

Comment: For `setarraynum`, keeping everything in there, make `arraynum` local and return a `std::vector` of that size.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea - I did this and now it seems to be working? - Strange. Thanks everyone for the quick responses. I will have to look into a debugger, I know nothing of them yet.

Comment: I haven't learnt anything about std::vector yet. I'm assuming I will learn this when I get onto my next topic of classes ect.

Comment: @DominicSore I think that is because you have an extra `\n` output somewhere in your code which is read in your first iteration. The `stream` object will terminate interpreting an integer once it encounters a non-digit. Go to debug it. I'm sure you can solve it yourself :).

Comment: That will more than likely be the case. Would you like to post an answer to this for the rep? Seeing as your solution worked.

Comment: Could you please provide your compiler version? Do you use VC++ or g++? I'm debugging on my box with g++ 4.2.1 when composing an answer. And I find that your original code works on my machine. Really wried!

Comment: Ah sorry found it. (The power of 'man' :P) - g++ -- version (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) 4.7.3

Comment: Would you like me to provide the whole code? Your comment about an extra \n may ring very true as I have a fair few in my code.

Comment: @DominicSore That could not be better ;). You can edit your post and append the whole sources. BTW, next time please `@Summer_More_More_Tea` or anyone else you want to reply to, thus we can get your message from the notification center at left upper corner in the page and no need to focusing on the OP. Thanks :D.

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea - Apologies. I have included the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you use `cin >> arraynum;` directly instead of read an integer in the `stringstream(mystr) >> arraynum;` paradigm.

From the C++ reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/ for `getline`

> If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is
>   not stored and the next input operation will begin after it.

So this is the problem.
As pointed by @Vaughn, you use `cin >> order;` in your `setorder` function, which will left the tailing `\n` in the input buffer.

The lesson learned by your code is when tackling I/O problem, make sure functions are invoked in the same paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
cout<<"Ascending or Descending [a/d]: ";
cin>>order;
```

you are reading the 'a' or 'd', but not the carriage return.

When you get to here:

```
cout<<"Please enter "<<arraynum<<" numbers:\n";
for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
  getline(cin, mystr);
```

The `getline` is going to treat whatever you typed after the 'a' or 'd' and before the carriage return as the line that it gets -- probably blank.

One way to solve it would be to add another `getline` after reading `order`:

```
cout<<"Ascending or Descending [a/d]: ";
cin>>order;
string rest_of_line;
getline(cin,rest_of_line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code slightly, and it behaves as expected. I would suggest you indicate to the user whether he should delimit his input, or how he should delimit. I would rather use a vector than an array. You are already not de-allocating your array - not that it matters, but it may in another program.

Also, I don't know why you use getline when cin already allows you to get the integers (see code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int arraynum;
int * array;
bool isin = false;
int input;
char order;

void insertionsortdesc(int a[]);
void insertionsortasc(int a[]);
void getarray(int a[]);
void isinarray(int a[], int b);

void setsearch();
void setarray();
void setarraynum();
void setorder();

int main(){

 std::cout<<"\n//// INPUT ////\n\n";

 setarraynum();
 setorder();
 setarray();
 setsearch();

 if(order=='a'){insertionsortasc(array);
 }else if(order=='d'){insertionsortdesc(array);};

 std::cout<<"//// OUTPUT ////\n\n";
 getarray(array);
 isinarray(array, input);

 return 0;
}

void setorder(){
 bool isvalid = false;

 while(!isvalid){
  std::cout<<"Ascending or Descending [a/d]: ";
  std::cin>>order;
  if(order=='a'||order=='d'){isvalid = true;
  }else{std::cout<<"Please enter a valid option!\n";};
 };

std::cout<<"\n";
}

void setarraynum(){
 std::cout<<"Please enter the size of your array: ";
 while( !( std::cin >> arraynum ) )
 {
   std::cout << "Please enter integer!";
 }
 array = new int [arraynum];
 std::cout<<"\n";
}

void setsearch(){
 std::cout<<"Search for (int): ";
 while( !(std::cin >> input) )
 {
   std::cout << "Please enter integer!" << std::endl;
 }
 std::cout<<"\n";
}

void setarray(){
 std::ostringstream msgStream;
 msgStream << "Please enter "<<arraynum<<" numbers:";
 std::cout << msgStream.str() << std::endl;

 for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
   if( !(std::cin >> array[n]) ){
     n = 0;
     std::cout << msgStream.str() << std::endl;
   }
 }
std::cout<<"\n";
}

void insertionsortdesc(int a[]){
 for(int n=1; n<arraynum; n++){
  int key = a[n];
  int j = n-1;
  while((j>=0)&&(a[j]<key)){
   a[j+1] = a[j];
   j -= 1;
  };
  a[j+1]=key;
 }
}

void insertionsortasc(int a[]){
 for(int n=1; n<arraynum; n++){
  int key = a[n];
  int j = n-1;
  while((j>=0)&&(a[j]>key)){
   a[j+1] = a[j];
   j -= 1;
  };
  a[j+1]=key;
 }
}

void isinarray(int a[], int b){
 for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
  if(a[n] == b){
   isin = true;
   break;
  };
 };

 if(isin){
  std::cout<<b<<" is present in the given array.";
 }else{
  std::cout<<b<<" is not present in the given array.";
 };

 std::cout<<"\n\n";
}

void getarray(int a[]){
 std::cout<<"Sorted array sequence: ";
 for(int n=0; n<arraynum; n++){
  std::cout<<a[n]<<", ";
 };
 std::cout<<"\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm not expecting to have perfect code yet as I have only started learning c++ recently and I am still coming to grasp with the concepts. I have not even started learning about classes. This program was to simply 'test' myself on what I have learnt over the past couple of days (as well as to learn the insertion sort algorithm).  I'm not even sure myself what you mean by de-limit :P. Also, I have already been informed of vectors but I am still learning the basics I have never seen the :: operator before now. (Except in other languages). Thanks again.

Comment: No sweat. currently you are using a space as delimiter. Therefore the user has to input integers seperated by spaces. This is OK, but just indicate that to the user. What would happen, e.g: if the user inputs 1;2;3 or 1,2,3... When I ran the code the first time it confused me from a usage perspective. The most important point to me is the one from @Summer_More... here above.

Comment: Ah I see. So just add something such as "Seperate by <space>?".